Tinny sound on 22.04 (Lenovo thinkpad L380)
Using 22.04 kernel x86_64 Linux 6.5.0-1020-oem
The audio sounds really tinny. In another post i read that it should be fixed for kernel 6.1.something but I'm still having bad quality (How to apply tinny and quiet sound fix on new Lenovo 7i running Ubuntu 22.04?)
Anyone know a possible fix?

If you already did the necessaru update, I would suggest checking in Settings > Sound > Output > Configuration and see what is selected there (for example "Head Set Head Unit (HSP/HFP)" or "High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink)".

Hey, thanks for the response! I cant see the configuration setting though, only a directional audio test and a balance slider. in pulsAudio, the configuration is set to analog stereo duplex/analog stereo output (these are the only ones in the list that work, all the others are HDMI output)

I do not know if this helps, but have you installed pavucontrol sudo apt install pavucontrol and tried different settings? I use only that instead of going to settings

hey @amar , yeah I have, its what i meant with pulseAudio in my previous comment. Only two configs work and they sound the same.

@Jerre I think your question is too specific and it applies only to one or few models, it may be best to ask it here https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu.

@amar thanks for the suggestion, also asked it there

@jarre is you need more after that, you can download pulseeffects, I wouldn't go to other ppa, all you need is autogain and limiter in there. https://susuthapa19961227.medium.com/trying-to-improve-audio-in-linux-with-pulseeffects-63f37ea5b320. If you are going to ask questions here pls, read the help files and accept the answer if it fixes your problem, This is not an answer, just a comment.

@jarre you should also post the link in your question, and push the Add information request instead so that they know you have answered.
